# Why can't I use my variable inside this if statement?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to add `1` to my variable `sum` but the compiler says

> the variable `sum` is unassigned

inside my if statement. I've tried moving it around but no matter what I do the variable is still unassigned.

```
static void Main()
{
    int sum;

    if(true)
    {
        sum += 1;
    }

    Console.Write(sum);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

How can change my code to fix this error and stop the compiler complaining?

Comment: `sum` is _declared_, not _defined_ - move it outside the loop and change it to `int sum = 0;`. Move the _declaration_ of `result` out of the loop as well

Comment: It's doesn't say it's "undefined", it says it's *"unassigned"*.  Assign it a value: `int sum = 0;`  Carefully read the error messages, they're what's telling you the problem.

Comment: what is `undefined/null + an integer`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, done

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The variable `sum` must have an initial value:

```
int sum = 0; //or any other value
```

in your code

```
static void Main()
{
    int sum = 0;

    if(true)
    {
        sum += 1;
    }

    Console.Write(sum);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

---

Think about, until `sum` is assigned a value, is has no defined value, it is undefined. What would the result of

```
undefined + 1
```

be, the compiler can't know so raises an error and halts compilation.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between a variable being *declared* ("I do declare *sum* to be a thing of type *int*") and it's value being *defined* (or, rather *assigned*).

Make sure a value has been *assigned* to them before you evaluate:

```
static void Main()
{
    // sum is declared as an int and an initial value of 0 is assigned to it
    int sum = 0;

    if(true)
    {
        sum += 1;
    }

    Console.Write(sum);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the sum is initialized inside the for loop and is is based on the previous value of the sum which is not given. There are two ways to solve the problem. Either initialize sum variable with zero (`int sum = 0`). Or initialize sum before the for loop. 
I think the second option makes more sense because you might want to have the cumulative result after the for loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

Before using any local variable, it has to be initialized or defined.
Since sum is not defined, you are getting this error